# How to supply streaming, i.e. X-Stream:true header using neo4jphp?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I am using neo4jphp with neo4j community 2.0.1,
and I need help about how to supply streaming, i.e. X-Stream:true header using neo4jphp?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The X-Streaming header is set for you. You don't have to do anything to enable it.

Comment: could you please elaborate? I am trying to use an angular library to populate a $scope array: https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe/blob/master/src/app.js In order to capture the first portion of the object, this link says I need x-stream to be true in the header: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-streaming.html What syntax do I use with Oboe to get that x-stream true in the header?

Comment: My answer is specific to the neo4jphp library. You'll need to ask the author of whatever Neo4j library or application framework you are using about setting headers for AJAX requests.